# Vue - Load External Components From Another Site

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I am trying to retrieve a vue component from an external site and load it in my app and cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Here is the full scenario;

- Site A (Internally Hosted Site) loads a VueJS application
- Site A requests a VueJS component from Site B (Internally Hosted Site, different sub domain)

  - Ideally, Site B would consist of .vue files either in their native .vue format or precompiled (maybe vue-cli for this?)
- Site A loads and renders the components in the application

Let's say I have a very simplistic component I want to load from Site B;

```js
{
    "template": "<div><span>{{message}}</span></div>",
    "data": function() {
        return { "message": "Hello World" };
    }
}
```

I've tried the following this with mixed results;

Inside my index.ts (using TypeScript)

```js
Vue.component('my-external-component', () => (Vue as any).http.get("http://test.local/test.js"));
```

and inside my .vue file

```html
<my-external-component></my-external-component>
```

This results in this comment being added to the DOM

```html
<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
```

however adding

```html
<component :is="my-external-component"></component>
```

Results in an empty comment being added to the DOM

```html
<!---->
```

I have also done a couple variations of this including using the cli to compile the template into a js file and attempting to load that, weird error about not being able to access `template.trim` or something along those lines.

Comment: Your _"very simplistic component"_ should have a `data` **function**, not a plain object

Comment: @Phil thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my local test as well as the question and it is still just adding the function comment. I have also updated the question to reflect this change to the component.

Comment: FYI, your `test.json` is no longer JSON

Comment: Do you think the MIME type being JSON could be causing some of my troubles? I will try changing it to JS because thats what it actually is now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your component definition is (or was) JSON and component `data` should be a function, you should transform the result before resolving the async component.

For example (using `fetch` because I don't know what `Vue.http` is)

```js
Vue.component('MyExternalComponent', () =>
  fetch('http://test.local/test.json').then(res => res.json()).then(defn => ({
    ...defn,
    data () { // transform defn.data into a function
      return defn.data
    }
  }))
)
```

[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/3eum8tnv/13/) using their [`/echo/json` service](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests#json) to simulate the external component definition.

---

Exporting a component definition from a remote `.js` file would be tricky.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this is fantastic however could you maybe expand a little bit on what the body of `jsonpCallbackFunctionName` would look like?

Comment: @AdamH not sure what you mean but what is `Vue.http`? Is it Axios? If so, I don't think it supports JSONP out-of-the-box

Comment: I can change to fetch, at this point we are in the POC phase. Vue.http comes from `vue-resource`, you might have seen it used like `this.$http` before.

Comment: @AdamH pretty sure [vue-resource is retired now](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4). I honestly don't recommend a JSONP option as it either introduces a server-side requirement on your remote resource or introduces globally scoped functions into your Vue app. I would just stick with transforming the JSON

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for all your help. I would upvote twice if I could but instead, you will have to take my undying gratitude.

Comment: @AdamH I've removed the JSONP example as it seems reasonably unworkable